# MarkupBuilder Rendering HTML SELECT Element

Tags: grails, groovy, markupbuilder

I have the following in a TagLib

```
select(name:"foo", value: "1") {
    option(value: "1", "hoo")
    option(value: "2", "goo")
}
```

When the page renders using this taglib, I'm not getting a SELECT element to show up.  Other elements like INPUT work just fine using the same type of markup.  I know it is getting to this code because I've set breakpoints and debugged.  Everything seems fine.  It just doesn't end up in the final markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change it to the following:

```
def formContainer = new MarkupBuilder(out)
....
formContainer.select(name:"foo", value: "1") {
    option(value: "1", "hoo")
    option(value: "2", "goo")
}
...
```